# Stray HTML comment element trashing Wordpress site on old browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, wordpress-theming

So I decided to check out my site today on an older computer, and to my horror the only thing it displayed was a solitary

```
<!-->
```

Oh dear. Here is the site in question: http://vibrolabs.com

So I look through the source and I believe I have found an uncaptured HTML comment that is commenting out essentially my entire website. This wasn't an issue on newer browsers but is not sitting well with Firefox 3.6.17 on Ubuntu 8.04

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://vibrolabs.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<div id="fb-root" style="width: 90;"></div> 

<!--<![endif]-->

<!-- SEO Ultimate (http://www.seodesignsolutions.com/wordpress-seo/) -->
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vibrolabs.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://vibrolabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/vibro-3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Vibro Labs" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1221720181" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
```

If you look at the lone [endif] line, you will see a single uncaptured comment (I think they are referred to as comments in HTML).

Any suggestions of where to start?

Comment: Can you strip out the comments and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: I suspect that removing the "uncaptured" `<!--` on the `<!--<![endif]-->` line would fix the problem. Perhaps older browsers are interpreting this as a nested-comment situation? (Nested comments are not part of standard HTML.)

Comment: @adj - It's not exactly nested comments. It's having an odd number of SGML comment open and comment close delimiters (i.e. `--`) which means that every subsequent `>` character is inside a comment and so the markup delimiter character for the comment is never encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered this problem due to the plugin 'Jamie Social Icons'.

The culprit conditional comment lies in line 126 of my jamie-social_icons.php.

The problem will resolve itself if you change

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
```

to become

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><!-->
```

Since updating the plugin file directly will cause you to lose your fix upon any plugin updates, it is important to implement a correction that will be persistent.

You'll notice that the code in question lies within the function definition for jamie_add_my_scripts().

The plugin uses add_action on the **'wp_enqueue_scripts'** and **'admin_enqueue_scripts'** hooks.

In your functions.php file or another file you can maintain control over, place the following override code:

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jamie_add_my_scripts' );
remove_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jamie_add_my_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jamie_override_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jamie_override_scripts' );
function jamie_override_scripts () {?>
<?php $options = get_option( 'jamie_social_options' ); if($options['insights'] == true){ ?>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<?php echo $options['insights']; ?>" />
 <?php } ?>
<?php if($options['lang'] == 'eng'){
$locale = 'en_GB';
} else if($options['lang'] == 'esp'){
$locale = 'es_ES';
} else if ($options['lang'] == 'pt'){
$locale = 'pt_PT';
} else if ($options['lang'] == 'de'){
$locale = 'de_DE';
} else if ($options['lang'] == 'fr'){
$locale = 'fr_FR';
} else {?>
<?php include( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/jamie-social-icons/locale/locale.php');?>
<?php } ?>
     <!--[if lte IE 8]><!-->
<div id="fb-root" style="width: 90;"></div>
<?php
wp_enqueue_script(
        'fb_ie8',
        'http://connect.facebook.net/'.$locale.'/all.js#xfbml=1');
        ?>
<!--<![endif]-->
<?php   wp_enqueue_script(
        'jamiesocial_tracking',
        plugins_url('/jamie-social-icons/js/googletracking.js')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jamietwitterlinkedin',
        plugins_url('/jamie-social-icons/js/head_twitterlinkedin.js')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in header.php of your twnetyeleven-child theme for the bad comment line. if there isn't a header.php in the child theme, look in header.php of the parent theme.

It, among other things, throws a validation error which could be bonking Firefox: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  vibrolabs.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//vibrolabs.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.